# Python Comparison of 2 HTML files and print only missing/added text

Tags: python, html

I am trying to compare two HTML files (rather big ones ~1 MB each) coming from CT scans. I want to compare them and make a file with only the missing/added text. Here's my code which makes a file with the differences:

```py
import difflib

first_file = ".../file1.html"
second_file = ".../file2.html"

first_file_lines = open(first_file).readlines()
second_file_lines = open(second_file).readlines()

diff = difflib.HtmlDiff().make_file(first_file_lines,second_file_lines,first_file,second_file)
diff_report = open(".../diff_report.html","w")
diff_report.write(diff)
diff_report.close()
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: i don't see any problem with your code. what is your question?

Comment: I just want to create a file which will print ONLY the missing/added text. Not all the lines.

Comment: you will find your answer in the docs for [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html), i guess the more common are `context_diff` and `unified_diff`

Comment: Thank you, I'll give them a try.